# What versions of libraries are shipped with WildFly 9.0.1.Final

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I was looking in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Documentation, but there is no info. Especially I want't to know version of hibernate-entitymanager & hibernate-jpamodelgen.

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to look at the pom.xml file for the 9.0.1.Final build:

https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/blob/9.0.1.Final/pom.xml

The relevant lines you are looking for are probably:

```
<version.org.hibernate>4.3.10.Final</version.org.hibernate
<version.org.hibernate.commons.annotations>4.0.5.Final</version.org.hibernate.commons.annotations
<version.org.hibernate.validator>5.1.3.Final</version.org.hibernate.validator>
<version.org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.1-api>1.0.0.Final</version.org.hibernate.javax.persistence.hibernate-jpa-2.1-api>
<version.org.hibernate.hql>1.1.0.Final</version.org.hibernate.hql>
<version.org.hibernate.search>5.2.0.Final</version.org.hibernate.search>
```

I don't think it ships with JPAModelGen at all, this is part of Hibernate tools which has gotten out of sync with Hibernate ORM releases. I believe it isn't being maintained as much due to JPA2 schema generation features.