# java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

Tags: hibernate, jpa, wildfly, wildfly-9

When I deploy my war file in wildfly9.0 I get following error; Any clue?

Hibernate version=5.0.1.Final

Hibernate validator version =5.2.1.Final

```
09:57:34,368 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 64) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit": java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:172)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:117)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:665)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:182)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AttributeConverterDefinition.<init>(AttributeConverterDefinition.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Configuration.java:2729)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.addAttributeConverter(Configuration.java:2673)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.buildHibernateConfiguration(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1153)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:853)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate4.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:154)
    ... 7 more

09:57:34,381 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (XNIO-1 task-9) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "test2dbwar.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit\"" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit.\"test2dbwar.war#test2dbwar-persistence-unit\": java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.lang.Class
    C
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildfly 9's included hibernate version is not 5. See [What versions of libraries are shipped with WildFly 9.0.1.Final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32026990/what-versions-of-libraries-are-shipped-with-wildfly-9-0-1-final)
Probably you have to use the correct version or exclude the servers' libraries using jboss-deployment-structure.xml. Or try Wildfly 10, which includes hibernate 5.

Comment: It looks versions are similar. I have more than 50 models and try to store them ..It was working fine and suddenly this issue pops up